# Getting Dell DA100 adapter working on Dell XPS 13 9360 running Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: drivers, usb, dell, 17.04, xps

I recently bought a Dell XPS13 9360 with Ubuntu (with Unity) 16.04. I also bought a [DA100 USB3 (ethernet, USB and video) adapter](http://accessories.ap.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=au&l=en&s=dhs&cs=audhs1&sku=492-11742).

While running 16.04 the adapter worked fine. When I upgraded to 17.04 (probably not "officially supported" but...) the adapter stopped working.

Dell have released an update to driver for the DA100, but unhelpfully they are only in "Windows OS" format.

I've tried using the [updated drivers from Displaylink](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu), but they have not worked.

I've taken a output of `usb-devices` before, and after installing the drivers. I've also dumped the driver install outputs.

They're all available in [the logfiles in this Dropbox share](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4rcfv6jv1juyr2o/AAA81V0bMM6r-syBebFVpsZfa?dl=0).

1. [usb-devices-probe-before-install-drivers.log](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4rcfv6jv1juyr2o/AACk0PviaQ-Fbc-DzPnq014Xa/1.%20usb-devices-probe-before-install-drivers.log?dl=0)
2. [install-da100-drivers.log](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4rcfv6jv1juyr2o/AAA8zMcP4_gQvPdNXpHkyN0Ua/2.%20install-da100-drivers.log?dl=0)
3. [usb-devices-probe-after-install-drivers.log](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4rcfv6jv1juyr2o/AACycUPqdxvzrJWJJbG6CewAa/3.%20usb-devices-probe-after-install-drivers.log?dl=0)

Has anyone gotten the Dell DA100 adapter working on a XPS 13 9360 running Ubuntu 17.04 Gnome 3?

Comment: I can't post more than 1 link, so:   

* [Dell DA100 adapter](http://accessories.ap.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=au&l=en&s=dhs&cs=audhs1&sku=492-11742)

* [Dell Windows drivers update for DA100](http://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukbsdt1/product-support/product/dell-universal-dongle-da100/drivers)

* [Displaylink Drivers for DA100 for Ubuntu](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu)

Comment: I'm curious as to why the rush to 17.04 which will be out of support January 2018 when 16.04 is supported until April 2021